# jquery star rating - Fyneworks.com

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to duplicate the rating plugin that is used elsewhere in our code but it is failing.  It may be that I have included the js and css in the wrong sequence.  Also the stars do not show up unless I change the class to STAR.  As it is I just get radio buttons.  The event never fires. When comparing the two pages ( the new one and the one that works) in dev tools, everything seems to be the same.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>     
    <link href='/assets/css/jquery.rating.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src='/assets/js/jquery.MetaData.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src='/assets/js/jquery.rating.pack.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
</head>

<script>
$(function(){
 $('.auto-submit-star').rating({
 **Uncaught type error: Object[object Object] has no method 'rating'**
  callback: function(value, link){
    // 'this' is the hidden form element holding the current value
            // 'value' is the value selected
            // 'element' points to the link element that received the click.
            alert("The value selected was '" + value + "'\n\nWith this callback function I can automatically submit the form with this code:\nthis.form.submit();");

            // To submit the form automatically:
            //this.form.submit();

            // To submit the form via ajax:
            //$(this.form).ajaxSubmit();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/services/Mentor.cfc',
                data: {
                    method: 'insertRating',
                    rating: value
                },
                //success: function(data){
                //  if (data == true) {
                //      alert('true!');
                //  }
                //  else {
                //      alert('false!');
                //  }
                //}
            });
        }
 });
});
</script>

<cfif qRating.recordCount GT 0>
            <input name="rating_#request.target_id#" type="radio" class="star required" value="#request.target_id#_1"<cfif qRating.rating EQ 1> checked="checked" disabled="disabled"</cfif> />
            <input name="rating_#request.target_id#" type="radio" class="star" value="#request.target_id#_2"<cfif qRating.rating EQ 2> checked="checked" disabled="disabled"</cfif> />
            <input name="rating_#request.target_id#" type="radio" class="star" value="#request.target_id#_3"<cfif qRating.rating EQ 3> checked="checked" disabled="disabled"</cfif> />
            <input name="rating_#request.target_id#" type="radio" class="star" value="#request.target_id#_4"<cfif qRating.rating EQ 4> checked="checked" disabled="disabled"</cfif> />
            <input name="rating_#request.target_id#" type="radio" class="star" value="#request.target_id#_5"<cfif qRating.rating EQ 5> checked="checked" disabled="disabled"</cfif> />
        <cfelse>
            <input name="rating_#request.target_id#" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star star required" value="#request.target_id#_1" />
            <input name="rating_#request.target_id#" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star star" value="#request.target_id#_2" />
            <input name="rating_#request.target_id#" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star star" value="#request.target_id#_3" />
            <input name="rating_#request.target_id#" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star star" value="#request.target_id#_4" />
            <input name="rating_#request.target_id#" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star star" value="#request.target_id#_5" />
        </cfif>
```

Comment: First of all, what are the questions you are hoping to have answered here?

Comment: Why does the event not fire?  Maybe it is firing and that's what is giving the error.  So, why the error?

Comment: you have to call your function in order to fire the event. try calling your function in document ready.

Comment: I made the change but there  is no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the script you pasted, you have a few issues.

1. The following line is not commented out right, `**Uncaught type error: Object[object Object] has no method 'rating'**`  What is this line doing in your code?  It appears to be some form of exception which you've inserted as a comment, but your comment syntax isn't right.  Remove it altogether, or if you must keep it, change it to this, `/**Uncaught type error: Object[object Object] has no method 'rating'**/`
2. The next issue is that you've commented out the 'Success' member method of the $ajax object, but left the comma in place above it.  This will throw an exception for the syntax alone.

EDIT:  Number 2 of my list above is actually inaccurate.  JS does allow the trailing comma in an object literal member collection.

Comment: ** is just lo let you know where the error is showing up.  I nnever enter into the function so the success function doesn't matter yet.

Comment: Pardon me.  That may have been the problem.  Still testing but it appears to work.  I get a little mean when I haven't had my snickers.  Sorry.